# From desktop to web application - challenges with views

Tags: tables

Our users are coming from desktop application, where they would often have multiple windows open on dashboard, containing smaller tables or forms.
They would often reference data between multiple windows, but also edit data.
This is quite a challenge on web (desktop only right now), because table data would be unreadable if we start splitting screens etc. - and at best, split views might be okay for 2 tables, where users often had 4 screens open.
I am curious to hear if anyone had similar challenge and how did you approach it from the layout perspective?

Comment: Do you mean a web application intended for some specific type of devices - for desktops, for tablets, for smartphones? Of for all types of devices? For instance, SAP Web Applications on desktops have pretty complex page structure with multiple tables on a single page and they are perfectly readable on any 15", 24" and 27" display. If you mean smartphones or tablets, then please edit your question correspondingly.

Comment: Can you clarify, When its Desktop application you can have multiple window which can share the data as and when there is an update in tables but in Web when you open multiple window and make changes in it, it doesn't auto reflect on other window is it correct?

Comment: @vignesh that is correct. And even though they can open multiple browser windows to look at other data/edit it while looking at "main" screen, it creates clutter and it's not a good way to work with.

Comment: Why would several windows be “not a good way to work with”? Web Applications still run on a desktop, and managing windows is something the desktop does well. Multi-monitor setups are entirely inaccessible to web applications without window management. Outlook Web allows to break out compose windows, which will open without the main menu etc. This is a common pattern and very useful.

Comment: @Andy Main issue we see that users forget to close the additional windows that open via e.g. links from main view, so they will sometimes reference incorrect data; for example, they will open holiday details on person A from main view - which will opens in a new browser window without menu as a table. 
Then they will click on person B in main view, but look at holiday details from person A mistakenly. Generally, they dont "clean up" after themselves, resulting in multiple windows from task "history" open on desktop tray.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is something that many people have had to deal with, and I have yet to see any universal solution to it.  Generally applications designed with fewer constraints first tend to have a lot less focus.  I would argue that designing with whatever your highest level of constraints are likely to be, is beneficial.

This exact problem is what triggered the **Mobile First** movement, as it's quite easy to move from a more constrained mobile design to a less constrained desktop design.  The classic book on the topic is [Mobile First by Luke Wroblewski](https://www.lukew.com/resources/mobile_first.asp), which although being a bit dates (from 2011), still has a lot of useful advice on the topic.  Generally speaking many (if not mostY web applications are essentially a way of reaching users on tablets as well as desktop use, and so many of the principles for mobile first still apply.

As general advice though, I've always had the best results by first **designing the mobile / more constrained application as if there weren't already a desktop / less constrained application** and working out what the best way to achieve every task would be.  **Task thinking** has been hugely beneficial to me and allows one to focus on the one thing that currently needs to be done.  You may find that doing this forces you to think very differently about how tasks should be performed rather than just how the layout should be translated from desktop to mobile or web.  I'm afraid that I can't give you much more than this for advice as the best way to translate desktop to mobile or web applications can be completely different from one application to another.